# Problem with CORS, Symfony + NGINX + Nuxt

Tags: symfony, nginx, fetch, nuxt.js, http-status-code-500

I have two docker containers with nuxt 3 for frontend and another with symfony and nginx for backend.

I never have hear about CORS so after some research I found that I needed a bundle named nelmio.

After installed it and configured it still getting the same error on my website (I have tested with Postman and everything works fine, I can register my user)

This is the error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register net::ERR_FAILED 500

Here is my nelmio_cors.yaml:

```
nelmio_cors:
  defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: [ '%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%' ]
    allow_methods: [ 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE' ]
    allow_headers: [ 'Content-Type', 'Authorization' ]
    expose_headers: [ 'Link' ]
    max_age: 3600
  paths:
    '^/api/':
      allow_origin: [ '*' ]
      allow_headers: [ '*' ]
      allow_methods: [ 'POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE' ]
      max_age: 3600
    '^/':
      origin_regex: true
      allow_origin: [ '^http://localhost:[0-9]+' ]
      allow_headers: [ 'X-Custom-Auth' ]
      allow_methods: [ 'POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE' ]
      max_age: 3600
      hosts: [ '^api\.' ]
```

In my env I have:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
```

In my nuxt I have this fetch call:

```
submitForm: function (data) {
      $fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    }
```

Anyone knows why I'm still getting the cors error?

**EDIT: I also tryed to set on the nginx config this line for cors but still not working...**

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "localhost";
```

**EDIT2: Ill put my nginx config here, maybe can be helpful:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /app/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

**EDIT3: Tryed on my nuxt 3 to set a proxy with nitro and vite but also not working...**

nuxt.config.ts:

with nitro:

```
nitro: {
    devProxy: {
        "/api": {
            target:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
            changeOrigin: true,
            prependPath: true,
        }
    }
},
```

with vite:

```
vite: {
        server: {
            watch: { usePolling: true },
            proxy: {
                '/backend': {
                    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                    ws: true,
                },
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you registered the bundle in your kernel? Add the NelmioCorsBundle to your application's kernel

Comment: try to replace all `127.0.0.1` with `localhost`

Comment: @dev_mustafa I'm using symfony flex, it has a recipe to install it automatically

Comment: @johnSmith tryed but still not working, also tryed add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * and using a regex with both on neilmo